# How to manipultate setup.py version with pre/post/rc/final/dev releases

Tags: python, pip, version, python-wheel

[pep 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#pre-releases) defines a list of legit versions for a python wheel, including:

1. .devN (developer version N)
2. .pre (pre-release)
3. rc (release candidate)

I want to release my project on a daily basis (i.e. have it released today as .dev0, tomorrow as .dev1, and so on...), and have an rc build, and then, if all goes correctly, have a formal release version.

In full names, I expect something like:

- [DEV]     name-x.y.z.dev0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
- [DEV]     name-x.y.z.dev1-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
- [R.C]     name-x.y.z.rc-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
- [2nd R.C] name-x.y.z.rc2-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
- [RELEASE] name-x.y.z-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
- [PATCH]   name-x.y.(z+1)-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl

---

1. Please correct me if something in my naming schema is off
2. Is there a common tool that does that for me, or do I need to edit setup.py with every commit? I only expected to edit it in final versions, but I guess I can have my daily CI pipeline edit it.

---

*I'm not (yet) using `python-versioneer`, and not (and not going to, I think) using `poetry`. I build my wheels using `./setup.py bdist_wheel` / `python -m build -w`.*

*I used to have a setup.py parser that handled "--version", but I think it is confusing and hard to maintain (it made me release wrong version once)*

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use the bumpversion package (https://pypi.org/project/bumpversion/)

you can find an exemple of what you want here : https://github.com/peritus/bumpversion